# Is protected inheritance transitive?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Lets say I have a listener interface defined as:

```
class Listener
{
   public:
      virtual void doSomething(void) = 0;
}
```

and an abstract class that inherits publicly from my interface:

```
class AbstractBase: public Listener
{
   public:
      virtual void doSomething(void){ ...do something }
}
```

My derived class inherits from my `AbstractBase` using **protected** inheritance:

```
class Derived: protected AbstractBase
{
   public:
      Derived(Caller &c){ c.register(this); }
}
```

My Caller class notifies listeners that register for events:

```
class Caller
{
   public:
      void register(Listener *listenerPtr){...add listenerPtr to some container }
      void raiseEvent(){...loop over registered listeners and call listenerPtr->doSomething();}
}
```

I then use the classes in the following manner:

```
int main(void)
{
   Caller caller;
   Derived derived(caller); // derived registers with caller in its constructor
   caller.raiseEvent();
}
```

In the above code, I see that `raiseEvent()` is allowed to invoke `listener.doSomething()`.  However, because I registered an instance of `Derived` as the listener, shouldn't `doSomething()` be protected (and hence uncallable from `Caller`), since it inherits it's implementation from AbstractBase via protected inheritance?

Comment: Presumably `Listener::doSomething()` should be virtual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access control is based on the *static* type, not the dynamic type. Therefore, since your `Caller` uses a pointer to `Listener`, it can use the interface defined by the `Listener` class. If it receives a pointer to a `Derived`, it's still basically treating it as a `Listener`, so from its viewpoint, `doSomething()` is public, regardless of what a derived class might do.

As an aside, I'd have some second thoughts about using `protected` inheritance. I've yet to see or hear of a good explanation of what it really means or a reasonable explanation of when or why you'd want to use it. In the D&E, Bjarne says (§13.9):

> Protected base classes were first described in the ARM and provided in Release 2.1. In retrospect, I think that `protected` is a case where "good arguments" and fashion overcame my better judgement and my rules for accepting new features.

Comment: I think that `protected` is a half-baked level of access. It's useful for some methods (non-pure virtual, constructor/copy constructor/assignment operator/destructor) but I find it utterly useless for inheritance (as pointed here) or attributes (difficult to ensure invariants).

Comment: @Matthieu: Yes, I guess i didn't quote it, but Bjarne does also say that he's fine with `protected` for member *functions* -- it was extending that to inheritance and member data that was really the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

View it as a set of interfaces to a object.  It is protected in the derived interface, not in the listener interface. Therefore anyone using the listener interface has access anyone using derived will see it as protected.  Basically it is a compile time check based on declared type .

Answer (score 0):

The access qualifiers are checked in compile-time, not in run-time. If `raiseEvent()` has an object and it knows that it's known to be of type `Listener`, then it's allowed to call `doSomething()` on it - that's a part of every `Listener`'s public interface.

If a method would receive a pointer to `Derived` object, then via protected inheritance it would **not** be known that this object inherits from AbstractBase and hence supports `raiseEvent()` - then the call would be illegal.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Derived: protected AbstractBase
{
public:
    Derived(Caller &c)
    {
            // Invokes `Caller::Register(Listener*)`. Cast to `Listener*` is
            // allowed because inside `Derived` member functions, `Listener`
            // is a visible base class. 
        c.register(this);
    }
};

class Caller
{
public:
    void register(Listener *listenerPtr);
    void raiseEvent()
    {
        // Because type of pointers is `Listener*` and not `Derived*`,
        // and because `Listener::doSomething()` is a *public*, member
        // function, it is accessile in this method.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you registered an instance of `Derived` as a listener has no importance : `Caller::raiseEvent` manipulates a `Listener` in which the `doSomething` method is public.

The inheritance relationship being protected is 'bypassed' as soon as `Derived` registers itself as a `Listener` on the `Caller` in its constructor : he exposes the fact that he's a `Listener`, thus having a `doSomething` public method.